# GetTextFromPage() method equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

Is there an equivalent for the `iTextSharp` GetTextFromPage() method in the new library `iText7`. When I try to add the nuget for `iTextSharp`, it says that they recommend to use `iText7`, but I didn't find the method in it.

Answer (score 1):

The class is still called `PdfTextExtractor` and the method is still called `GetTextFromPage`. Here is a code sample:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    String pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(i), new LocationTextExtractionStrategy()));
}
```

Comment: As the op did not find the class, you may also want to add the respective package here.

Comment: thanks alexey. There is some difference in which this is implemented (from the older one in iTextsharp) but it worked.